# SUM the COUNT results from a database table with two different value

Tags: sql

I'd like to count total events, which can have two different values, and I could not figure out how to merge them together. My query is the following:

```
SELECT TOP(20) 
    [MatchEvents].[PlayerID], [MatchEvents].[EventType], 
    COUNT([MatchEvents].[ID]) AS [TOTAL]
FROM
    [MatchEvents]
INNER JOIN 
    [Match] ON [MatchEvents].[MatchID] = [Match].[ID] 
            AND [Match].[Season] = 1 
WHERE 
    ([MatchEvents].[EventType] = 0 OR [MatchEvents].[EventType] = 1)
GROUP BY 
    [MatchEvents].[PlayerID], [MatchEvents].[EventType] 
ORDER BY 
    [TOTAL] ESC
```

Current output:

| PlayerID | EventType | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 8 |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 0 | 8 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 0 | 8 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |

Expected output:

| PlayerID | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 11 |

How could I merge my current results further?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to remove the EventType from the SELECT and GROUP BY clauses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected results it appears you just need to remove grouping by `EventType`

I would suggest the following:

```
select top(20) me.PlayerID,  Count(*) as Total
from MatchEvents me
join [Match] m on m.Id = me.MatchId and m.Season = 1
where me.EventType in (0, 1)
group by me.PlayerID
order by Total desc;
```

Comment: That was it! ** facepalm ** Thanks!